# Is a version of TASM available for free?

Tags: tasm

Has any version of TASM (Turbo Assembler) been released for free by the copyright holder?

I know that the following products have been released for free (available from [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/PopularDownloads.aspx?prodid=2)), but they don't contain TASM (*tasm.exe*, *tasmx.exe* or *tasm32.exe*):

- Turbo Pascal 1.0
- Turbo Pascal 3.02
- Turbo Pascal 5.5 (1989-05-02)
- Turbo Pascal 7.0 (1992-10-30)
- Turbo C 2.01
- Turbo C++ 1.01 (1991-02-28)
- Borland C++ Compiler 5.5 (2000-02-16)

These products do contain TASM, but they have never been released for free (as far as I know):

- Borland C++ 2.0
- Borland Pascal 7.0 and 7.01

I've also checked that Delphi 2 (1996-06) doesn't contain TASM.

Please note that for this question I'm not interested in assemblers similar to TASM (of which I know of [LZASM](https://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=308), which is freeware) or other alternatives to TASM.

Comment: archive.org has some files eg https://archive.org/details/borland-turbo-c-pascal-assembler-debugger-turbo-debugger and https://archive.org/details/borland-turbo-debugger-profiler-assembler I don't know how they justify hosting this though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Turbo Assembler has never been made available for free by its copyright holder. I don’t have a reference to prove this negative.

(I’m ignoring possible releases on magazine cover discs, since they are only officially available to people buying the magazine. I’m not aware of one of those either.)

Note that Borland France also released Turbo Pascal 7 for free, with a specific package of example programs prepared by a current colleague of mine. I don’t think this is available for download anywhere official now.

Comment: FYI Here is a reference to Turbo Pascal 7 for free: http://www.sigayret.fr/st/progpas/telechargerpascal.htm . It was available on www.borland.fr/download/compilateurs/ on 2001-01-15. To get the download link, one had to register with an e-mail address.